Can someone explain the 'levels' in the Python Logging module and whether Loggin can be setup in a def function?
I am fairly new to Python and now trying to use Logging rather that Print to follow and debug my code. The problem is that I am trying to setup Logging parameters using a def inline function and it is not working. I am using def because the parameter list is long and can be reused.
However by trial and error (definitely not by understanding!) I find that the following code works:
def setuplogging():
    # logging_example

    #import logging

    # When setting up logging, define the level using capitals because logging.debug is seen as a function, logging.DEBUG is the level id.
    
    # Create a custom logger
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__) #The variable __name__ contains the dotted name of the current module.
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) #WARM is default

    # Create handlers
    c_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    f_handler = logging.FileHandler('E:\data\computing\software\programming\scripts\LOGFILE.log')
    c_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    f_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    # Create formatters and add it to handlers
    c_format = logging.Formatter('%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    f_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    c_handler.setFormatter(c_format)
    f_handler.setFormatter(f_format)

    # Add handlers to the logger
    logger.addHandler(c_handler)
    logger.addHandler(f_handler)

    logger.info('def This is a test of an info message')
    logger.warning('def This is a warning')
    logger.error('def This is an error')

import logging
logging.warning('This is a trial of basic logging')
setuplogging()
logging = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logging.info('Script This is a test of an info message')
logging.warning('Script This is a warning')
logging.error('Script This is an error')

However, without the "logging = logging.getLogger(name)" after the function call, the last three logging statements in the main script do not do anything. Why is this?
The output I get is doubled - dont know why. See extract from the console log:
https://i.sstatic.net/4ap6Io5L.png
Thanks in advance for your help.

logging = logging.getLogger(__name__) overwrites your import of the logging module with a logger, which is not what you want to do.

But without that line I dont get logging displays in the main script.  So if that is not what I want to do then what do I want to do?

Your example is only configuring handlers for a single logger.
If you skip the logging = logging.getLogger(__name__) line, logging.info() will mean "log info to the root logger", and since you haven't configured anything on the root logger, nothing will be logged.
You generally want to configure the root logger (that you can acquire with logger.getLogger() without arguments) to handle most everything (up to your desired level), and then separately configure other loggers to do things in other ways.
import logging

# Configure the root logger
root_logger = logging.getLogger()
root_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
c_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
c_format = logging.Formatter('%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
c_handler.setFormatter(c_format)
root_logger.addHandler(c_handler)

# Log using a named logger
logger = logging.getLogger("mylibrary.mymodule")
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)  # This would be done during initialization

logger.info('This is a test of an info message')
logger.warning('This is a warning')
logger.error('This is an error')
logger.debug("You can't see this")  # The level is set to INFO

# Log onto the root logger
logging.info('Script This is a test of an info message')
logging.warning('Script This is a warning')
logging.error('Script This is an error')

This prints out
mylibrary.mymodule - INFO - This is a test of an info message
mylibrary.mymodule - WARNING - This is a warning
mylibrary.mymodule - ERROR - This is an error
root - INFO - Script This is a test of an info message
root - WARNING - Script This is a warning
root - ERROR - Script This is an error


AKX, thanks for putting so much effort into answering.
Although I have read innumerable 'how to ' and 'introduction' web sites, I still have no idea what root logger is and why I might need more than one logger. Nor do I know what 'mylibrary.mymodule' would be and why I need it or how to setup.
Nor have I been able to move forward with my original question about can I put all that logging configuration code into a inline function so I can use it in other applications.
I think I will have to go back to using 'print'; although I will miss the ability to write to a log file.

The idea with the log = logging.getLogger(__name__) pattern is that __name__ is the name of the module – if you have that line in davys_pkg/widgets.py, then log.info("Widget initialized") there would have the logger name davys_pkg.widgets, and since loggers are hierarchical, you could configure the davys_pkg logger to log to a file, and everything else onto the screen, etc. Have you read the official logging HOWTO?

AKX - I have a top university education in engineering and I still dont understand a single word of your kind attempt to explain in simple terms.
I have read the Logging Howto but unfortunately it doesnt start out basic enough! Lots of how to do it but little about the underlying concepts.
So back to 'print' it will be.

Concepts, simply: log records are handled by handlers and formatted into text by formatters (where applicable). Log records of a given level are emitted by calling e.g. .warning() on a logger, and they're handled by that logger's handlers (unless filtered by a filter on that logger) and/or propagated upwards (when .propagate = True on the handler), up to the root logger, which handles whatever isn't handled otherwise.

OK I think I can get that now. Following on from you success in getting it into my thick head, do you fancy a stab at answering my original question?
"I am trying to setup Logging parameters using a def inline function and it is not working. I am using def because the parameter list is long and can be reused. "
So is a reusable inline function to set up the logging parameters not possible?

It's possible. Any code that can be outside a function (there's no such thing as a "def" or a "def inline") can be inside a function, but it's not quite clear what you want to achieve here. If it helps, since loggers are hierarchical, if you adhere to using a convention for your app's logger names, e.g. logging.getLogger("myapp.widgets") and logging.getLogger("myapp.plumbing") or whatever, you can simply configure the myapp logger once, and leave the sub-loggers unconfigured.

OK, thanks everybody who tried to help. This is the script, using an inline function, which now works:
 # Python's standard Logging Module example

def setuplogging():
    # When setting up logging, define the level using capitals because logging.debug is seen as a function, logging.DEBUG is the level id.
    
    # Create a custom logger
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__) #The variable __name__ contains the dotted name of the current module.
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) #WARN is default

    # Create handlers
    c_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    f_handler = logging.FileHandler('E:\data\computing\software\programming\scripts\LOGFILE.log')
    c_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    f_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    # Create formatters and add it to handlers
    c_format = logging.Formatter('%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    f_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    c_handler.setFormatter(c_format)
    f_handler.setFormatter(f_format)

    # Add handlers to the logger
    logger.addHandler(c_handler)
    logger.addHandler(f_handler)
    # Test Messages
    logger.info('def This is a test of an info message')
    logger.warning('def This is a warning')
    logger.error('def This is an error')
    return logger

import logging
logger = setuplogging()

# Test Messages
logger.info('Script This is a test of an info message')
logger.warning('Script This is a warning')
logger.error('Script This is an error')


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
